# ignore certain word on if condition

Tags: python, if-statement

How to create an if condition on a string that fails if there is anything other than "Ignore keyword" followed by "foo- "
Eg: following two strings should pass and fail respectively:

> success = '\nrandom stuff,foo-    Ignore keyword\nfoo+    Ignore
>   keyword\n     random stuff;\nfoo-    Ignore keyword'
>
> fail = '\nrandom stuff,foo-    Ignore keyword\nfoo+    Ignore
>   keyword\n     random stuff;\nfoo-    Ignore keyword\nfoo-   this
>   should fail'

I was trying along this line and wasn't able to make it work:

```
In [80]: if 'foo- ' in fail or re.search('.*Ignore.*keyword', fail):
    print 'fail'
   ....:
fail

In [81]: if 'foo- ' in success or re.search('.*Ignore.*keyword', success):
    print 'fail'
   ....:
fail
```

Comment: Could you explain how would you use this feature? Do you want to use it e.g. while reading the lines of a file or something similar?

Comment: no, this will be one single string.

Comment: It's not clear what rules you're trying to enforce. Why should the second one fail?

Comment: @A.Archer I managed to answer to your question a few weeks ago. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

**Now it does exactly what were you asking for:**

```
success = '\nrandom stuff,foo- Ignore keyword\nfoo+ Ignore keyword\n random stuff;\nfoo- Ignore keyword'

fail = '\nrandom stuff,foo- Ignore keyword\nfoo+ Ignore keyword\n random stuff;\nfoo- Ignore keyword\nfoo- this should fail'
# to be successful only "Ignore keyword" after "foo- "
elem_to_search = "foo- "
keyword = "Ignore keyword"

def check_sentence(elem_to_search, keyword, string_to_check):
    index = 0
    keyword_first = len(elem_to_search)
    keyword_last = len(elem_to_search) + len(keyword)

    while index < len(string_to_check):
        index = string_to_check.find(elem_to_search, index)
        if index == -1:
            break
        elif string_to_check[index + keyword_first : index + keyword_last] == keyword:
            index += len(elem_to_search)
        else:
            print "fail"
            break
```

**check_sentence("foo- ", "Ignore keyword", success)** will pass

**check_sentence("foo- ", "Ignore keyword", fail)** will print fail.

Comment: That will not work because I am trying to fail on "foo-  anything", but not fail on "foo-  Ignore keyword"

Using your suggested way:
`
In [82]: fail_criteria = 'foo- '

In [83]: if fail_criteria in success:
   ....:     print 'fail'
   ....:
fail

In [84]: if fail_criteria in fail:
    print 'fail'
   ....:
fail
`

Comment: that does not work either
to be more clear:
'foo- Ignore keyword' <-- pass (dont care)
'foo- anything else'  <--- fail

Comment: This new version of the answer works fine as expected!

Comment: Any news on this question? the answer works fine now!